# javax.validation getting ignore from jersey

Tags: jersey

I am trying to use Jersey to get JSON request from the user to create vendor

```
@POST
@Produces({APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("create")
public Response create(VendorTO vendorTO) throws Exception {
```

But before it converts in vendorTO object I want to validate it with javax.validation

I have added constraints in my pojo like this

```
{@JsonSerialize(include=Inclusion.NON_NULL)
  public class VendorTO {
@NotNull
private Integer userId;
@Size(min = 2)
private String vendorName;
private String address1;
private String address2;
private String city;
private String state;
private String country;
private String email;
private String phone;
```

}

but it doesnt seems to be working. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the framework that the parameter should be [`@Valid`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/Valid.html)ated:

```
@POST
@Produces({APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("create")
public Response create(@Valid VendorTO vendorTO) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help but its still not working :(. Now I have a doubt that do jersey supports javax.validation?

Comment: Well, you _can_ always just run the validation yourself, though it's certainly not as concise.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like this will work 'like magic' until [JAX-RS 2.0](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Parameter-validation-jsr-303-again-td6861412.html).

Answer (score 0):

At this point, it appears Jersey does not support [JSR 303 natively](http://markmail.org/message/66p4dqeryzq6n5mr). You might have to write some ResourceFilters and handle the validation manually.